# how to write lpad function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm converting oracle to PostgreSQL. While converting for this below line

```
P_OTP := LPAD(W_OTPNUM, 6, '0');
```

I'm getting error like *function lpad(integer, integer, unknown) does not exist*.
Please help me to solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`W_OTPNUM` seems to be a number. You cannot pad a number, only a string.

```
LPAD(W_OTPNUM::TEXT, 6, '0')
```